# Cannot find second element in Selenium even though it exists

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script which looks for a gym class name and then clicks on the appropriate button. It works perfectly when there is one gym class of that name. But when there are two then I can not get it to choose the second.

This is the script:

```
className = 'Zumba'


WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'" + className + "')][2]/parent::div/parent::a[@onclick]")))
```

If I change the [2] to [1] then it works and selects the first element, but [2] does not select the second.

First element:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 class column1" style="">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="getClassDetails('265136', '614617')" class="studio">    <div>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <p style="padding:10px 25px 0 25px;font-size:13px">Zumba</p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:left;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
            350 cals
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;float:right;padding:0;margin:0;">
            45 mins
        </p>
    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin:-5px 5px 5px; background-color: #C52B2B; box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) inset;">Fully Booked</div>
                        
</a>
            
</div>
```

Second element:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 class column1" style="">
                
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="getClassDetails('265135', '614617')" class="studio">    <div>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <p style="padding:10px 25px 0 25px;font-size:13px">Zumba</p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:left;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
            350 cals
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;float:right;padding:0;margin:0;">
            45 mins
        </p>
    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin:-5px 5px 5px; background-color: #C52B2B; box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) inset;">Fully Booked</div>
                        
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="getClassDetails('265185', '614617')" class="spinstudio">    <div>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <p style="padding:10px 25px 0 25px;font-size:13px">Indoor Cycling </p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:left;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
            400 cals
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;float:right;padding:0;margin:0;">
            45 mins
        </p>
    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin: -5px 5px 5px; background-color: #2d7698; box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) inset;">Join Waiting List</div>
                        
</a>
                                
</div>
```

Any help to troubleshoot would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//p[contains(text(),'" + className + "')])[2]/parent::div/parent::a[@onclick]")))
```

The trick is to enclose `(//p[contains(text(),'" + className + "')])` before selecting nth node.

Comment: I'm wondering if `"(//p[contains(text(),'" + className + "')]/parent::div/parent::a[@onclick])[2]"` would work, too?

Comment: It should. Also `f'(//a[.//p[contains(., "{className}")]])[2]'` should work.